# UIImage view encode to base64

Tags: ios, uiimageview, swift2, base64, xcode7

I'm trying to encode UIImage as base64 string. My code is this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var photoImageView: UIImageView!

let image : UIImage = UIImage(named:"photoImageView")!
let imageData:NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)!
let strBase64:String = imageData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
```

the problem is that I get this kind of error : "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: which line did you get this error?

Comment: this one: let image : UIImage = UIImage(named:"photoImageView")!

Comment: make sure you have "photoImageView" added to project, check for spelling, uppercase,lowercase.

Comment: what do you mean? isn't it defined in @IBOutlet weak var photoImageView: UIImageView! or should it be somewhere else also?

Comment: I think what you need is `let image = photoImageView.image`. UIImage is initialised with image asset (jpeg, png, etc..), not initialised with an image view.

Answer (score 0):

Prasad's comment is likely the issue you're running into.

For any functions that return optionals, I usually use `if - let` syntax or guards to make sure I don't accidentally unwrap a nil.

```
if let image = UIImage(named:"photoImageView") {
    if let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) {
        // swift 2
        // imageData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)

        // swift 3
        let strBase64:String = imageData.base64EncodedString(options: [.lineLength64Characters])
    } else {
        print("can't get PNG representation")
    }
} else {
    print("can't find photoImageView image file")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Enix your comment did the trick. Solution to my problem was this line

```
let image = photoImageView.image
```

As you have pointed out UIImage is initialised with image asset, not with an image view